# How to make web-app using html5 and REST and after copy front-end code into mobile app uisng cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, rest

Is it possible to create mobile application from web portal using Cordova or etc.frameworks

I will have a web portal:

- `HTML5` front end
- `J2EE` back and with `JAX-RS`

And is it possible to get pages and put pages into mobile app without rewriting code and build mobile app.

Comment: Yes you can create mobiles apps this way.

Comment: do you have a link for examples ?

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/
The only thing you have to think about is, that your webapplication frontend probably does not fit into an mobile app. If it's build for web- and mobile applications there is no problem creating mobile apps with apache cordova

Comment: You could use Ionic over Cordova and then check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282230/re-use-the-phonegap-cordova-mobile-app-code-for-web-application/34283842#34283842

Answer (score 0):

You could try my open source library [**BlackTie.js**](https://www.github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie).

---

### It has the functions that you might need to use rest services like :

You can call an oauth service with the function `openOauth(baseurl, tokenurl, clientid, apikey, scope, responsetype, other, callback);`.

The parameters :

- `baseurl` is the url of the service which you want to use.
- `clientid` is the client is you received when you registered for this service.
- `scope` is the space delimited string of scopes you want to use.
- `callback` is the function you want to run when oauth has finished.
- `apikey` is the api key you got when you registered for the service. **(optional)**
- `responsetype` is either token or code based on the service. **(optional)**
- `tokenurl` is the url to get the token from the service if you are using a code type oauth ie. Oauth 1.0. **(optional)**
- `other` is any other information that you would like to append in the queries. **(optional)**

Optional parameters can be set to `null` or `""`.

You can perform a get or post request with the function `sendRequest(url, method, data, headers, callback);`.

The parameters :

- `url` is the url where you want to send a request.
- `method` is either `get` or `post`.
- `data` is the data to send with the post request. **(optional)**
- `headers` is any custom headers you want to send. **(optional)**
- `callback` is the function you want to run when oauth has finished.

Optional parameters can be set to `null` or `""`. If you are using a get request `data` won't be necessary.

Comment: You should put in your answer (1) that it is a library you created, (2) what part(s) of your library can be used to solve the problem and (3) how it should be used.