# Adapting HTML, CSS, in cordova application

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova

I just want to ask some questions to make this point clear for me.

If I got a responsive website template that uses HTML, CSS, CSS animation, AngularJS, and angularJs animation, and insert that code in my views in cordova app. Will mobile app works properly, or I will face a problems in performance and appearence .. ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a too general question...

it depends on which type of animation, styles, complexity of UI, ...

Certainly it is possible to adapt a single page site to a SPA (single page application) but with some work.

Here is a post regarding code re-use between Cordova app and Mobile web app:

[Re-use the Phonegap Cordova mobile app code for web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282230/re-use-the-phonegap-cordova-mobile-app-code-for-web-application/34283842#34283842)